# No values ​are entered into Mybatis SQL in Spring project

Tags: java, mysql, spring, mybatis

I'm working on a spring project with IntelliJ.

My DAO

```
// Board Insert
    public int boardInsert(String rb_uid, String rb_sub, String r_name, String r_address, String rb_contents, int rb_rating) {
        System.out.println("===== Board Insert DAO =====");

        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("rb_uid", rb_uid);
        map.put("rb_sub", rb_sub);
        map.put("r_name", r_name);
        map.put("r_address", r_address);
        map.put("rb_contents", rb_contents);
        map.put("rb_rating", rb_rating);

        return sqlSession.insert("ResBoardMapper.boardInsert", map);
    }
```

My XML

```
<insert id="boardInsert">
        <!-- Duplicate Check -->
        INSERT IGNORE
        INTO m_restaurant(r_name, r_address)
        VALUES(#{r_name }, #{r_address });

        <!-- INSERT -->
        INSERT INTO m_resboard(rb_rid, rb_uid, rb_sub, rb_rating, rb_contents)
        VALUES((SELECT r_id FROM m_restaurant WHERE r_name = #{r_name }), #{rb_uid }, #{rb_sub }, #{rb_ratring }, #{rb_contents });
    </insert>
```

Error

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: ### Error updating database. Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn:135) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO m_resboard(rb_rid, rb_uid, rb_sub, rb_rating, rb_contents) ### The error may involve defaultParameterMap ### The error occurred while setting parameters ### SQL: INSERT IGNORE INTO m_restaurant(r_name, r_address) VALUES(?, ?); INSERT INTO m_resboard(rb_rid, rb_uid, rb_sub, rb_rating, rb_contents) VALUES((SELECT r_id FROM m_restaurant WHERE r_name = ?), ?, ?, ?, ?); ### Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn:135) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO m_resboard(rb_rid, rb_uid, rb_sub, rb_rating, rb_contents) ; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn:135) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO m_resboard(rb_rid, rb_uid, rb_sub, rb_rating, rb_contents) org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
```

When checking the console before executing the query, the value is inserted normally.
Please tell me how to resolve BadSqlGrammarException. The login function runs normally.

Comment: It probably works if you add `allowMultiQueries=true` to the JDBC connection URL. But it is usually better to put each INSERT in separate `<insert>` and execute them in the same transaction.